# Fitting a partially clustered/nested design using lmer

Tags: multilevel-analysis, lme4-nlme

I have a study where clustering occurs in one condition but not the other. In the treatment group I have repeated measurements on individuals who are nested within families. And in the control condition I only have repeated measurements on individuals, but no clustering due to family.

Some dummy data would look like this

```
       time id family     group           y
    1     0  1      1 treatment  0.58407458
    2     1  1      1 treatment  0.57629394
    3     2  1      1 treatment  1.16558208
    4     0  2      1 treatment -1.03117769
    5     1  2      1 treatment  0.87066744
    6     2  2      1 treatment  0.42714038
    7     0  3      1 treatment  0.62503878
    8     1  3      1 treatment  0.11275242
    9     2  3      1 treatment  0.66396118
    10    0  4      2 treatment  0.07094150
    11    1  4      2 treatment -0.44600018
    ..    ....      .  .......    .......
    28    0 10      NA   control -1.66283938
    29    1 10      NA   control  1.17574655
    30    2 10      NA   control -0.59692375
    31    0 11      NA   control -1.94929165
    32    1 11      NA   control  0.88162730
    33    2 11      NA   control -2.38991654
    ..    ....      .  .......    .......
```

If both conditions were nested within families I would run

```
lmer(y ~ time*group + (1 | family/id), data=study_data)
```

But I don't think this fits the right model in this scenario? What would be the correct way to fit a partially clustered design?

Comment: Although I never thought of that, so don't know the answer, I would suggest to read this http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3987820/